# Pipelines with asyncio coroutines

Tags: python-3.x, pipeline, python-asyncio, coroutine

I'm new with asyncio and I'm implemented some kind of pipeline using asyncio coroutines.
The main idea is to have different pipelines with coroutines that are connected to
aggregate information in a payload and after that save the payload in a database.

```
class ExamplePipeline(PipelineBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        PipelineBaseClass.__init__(self)
        self.stages = [get_some_info, build_message,n,..,save_to_db]
        self.wrapper = self.connect(self.stages)

    def connect(self, stages):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            data_out = yield from stages[0](*args, **kwargs)
            for stage in stages[1:]:
                data_out = yield from stage(data_out)
            return data_out
        return wrapper

    def run(self, data_in):
      asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self.wrapper(data_in))
```

The functions for each stage are coroutines suppose something like

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def get_some_info(payload):
      payload = call_an_endpoint
      return payload

@asyncio.coroutine
def build_message(payload):
      #do some logic
      return payload
```

I have a new requirement in which the build_message co routine in some cases
needs to fork the rest of the pipeline, this is that the rest of the stages
n..save_to_db must be executed x times with different payloads since
build_message.

```
[get_some_info, build_message -> payload 1 [n, .. , save_to_db]
                                 payload 2 [n, .. , save_to_db]
                                 payload x [n, .. , save_to_db]
```

So at finish I have x different messages on the db.

How can I implement my new feature in this context?